# How can i pass bytes in dict when using requests.post(url, json=dict)

Tags: python, python-requests

i have a web server `p`, `p` has an api method is `POST`(api url like http://localhost/send_email) could send email, api code like below

```py
def send_email()
    data = request.get_json()

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # 2. 设置邮箱服务器信息
    mailserver = "smtp.qq.com"  # 邮箱服务器地址

    msg['From'] = data['sender']  # 邮件发送者名字
    msg['To'] = ';'.join(data['receivers'])  # 邮件接收者名字
    msg['Subject'] = data['mail_subject']  # 邮件主题

    # 4. 正文
    text = MIMEText(data['text'], 'html', 'gbk')
    msg.attach(text)

    # 5. 构造附件
    attachments = data['attachments_json']
    for attach_name, attachment in attachments.items():
        an = pathlib.Path(attach_name).name

        att = MIMEApplication(bytes(attachment, 'utf-8'))
        att.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=an)
        msg.attach(att)

        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.connect(mailserver)
        server.login(data['sender'], data['passwd'])  # 登录发送发邮箱
        server.sendmail(data['sender'], data['receivers'], msg.as_string())
        server.quit()

    return {'result_code': 1}
```

Then i have another server `b`, i write a python script to generate excel, code like below

```py
subject = '123'

flag = True
# 如果查询结果不为空，就构造附件发出邮件
file_list = None

p_parameters = {
    'sender': '123@qq.com',
    'passwd': '123',
    'receivers': ['123@163.com'],
    'mail_subject': subject,
}

p_url = 'http://localhost/send_email'

if len(bill_data) != 0:
    # 构造附件
    text, file_list = work_order_process(bill_data)

    p_parameters['text'] = text

    attachments_json = {}

    # # 添加邮件附件
    for file in file_list:
        attachments_json[file] = str(open(file, 'rb').read())
    p_parameters['attachments_json'] = attachments_json

    try:
        resp = requests.post(p_url, json=p_parameters)
        
        logging.warning(resp.json())
        response = resp.json()
        if 'result_code' in response:
            code = resp.json()['result_code']
            if code == 0:
                print({'code': -1, 'message': '邮件发送失败，请检查'})
            else:
                print({'code': 0, 'message': '邮件发送成功'})
        else:
            print({'code': -1, 'message': '邮件发送失败，请检查'})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.with_traceback(e.__traceback__))
        if file_list:
            for file in file_list:
                if os.path.exists(file):
                    os.remove(file)
# 如果未查询到结果，发邮件通知

if file_list:
    for file in file_list:
        if os.path.exists(file):
            os.remove(file)
```

function `work_order_process()` in it could generate excel files and `file_list` contains file path
when i run this script, an error occurred `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

Tips: `resp = requests.post(p_url, json=p_parameters)` this code couldn't change because server `p` cannot controlled by myself.

How can i change my code that i could send email successfully

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can turn bytes into unicode-string by decoding it. Does that help?